# How to check which Windows 10 version I'm using? (Like 1703)

Tags: windows-10, version

Probably stupid question. I googled for it but what I found is that it should be in the place as in screenshot below
[image]

Also, here by typing "winver" into search but I believe this is wrong number [image]

Comment: because it's the 'build' not the 'version'… though maybe because they didn't start calling it 1507 until a while after release [not sure when they changed that convention]

Comment: @Tetsujin - 1507 (RTM), 1511 (November 2015 Update), 1607 (Anniversary Update).  It wasn't until 1703 did they stop having codenames for the feature updates.

Comment: @Tetsujin - "version" refers to the build (10240) which is considered to be `Windows 10 version 1507` which was known as Windows 10 RTM at the time of release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has a list - [Windows 10 version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history)

From which you can see that is still on the very first release, 1507 from 2015 - well out of support unless you have a mission-critical machine.

Newer builds give both the version & build numbers in `winver`

[image]

From comments, if you want the full resource in greater detail, then see Microsoft [Windows 10 Update History](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464619/windows-10-update-history)

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: @Ramhound - I thought of posting that one, but it's far too convoluted for a simple lookup build>version & is going to be a constantly-moving resource set, across a myriad pages. I added the link into the answer, for completeness.

Comment: @Tetsujin - The update history will always be current, Wikipedia, might not always be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

> I googled for it but what I found is that it should be in the place as in the screenshot below
>
> [image]

You are running `Windows 10 Enterprise 2015 LTSC`.  Due to the fact you are running `Windows 10 Enterprise 2015 LTSC`, it means you will never be offered a feature update through Windows Update.  You will need to have the rights to `Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSC` or `Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC` in order to upgrade to those versions.

> I believe this is the wrong number

It is not possible for `winver` to report the incorrect version of Windows 10.

Source:

- [What's new in Windows 10 Enterprise 2015 LTSC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/ltsc/whats-new-windows-10-2015)
- [Windows 10 update history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000823)